# Request is known only when I do not use JSON.stringify

Tags: node.js, json, axios

I get this weird error when I use JSON.stringy, I get an empty request on my server side.

```
export const login = ({email,password}) => async dispatch => {
  const config = {
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  //Not working
  //const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });
  //working
  const body = {email, password};

  alert(body);
  try {
    const res = await axios.post("/api/auth",body , config);
    dispatch(loadUser());
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;
  }
};
```

`app.use(express.json());` in server.js file

This works but if I use const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });
 instead I get an empty request.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: If I use const body = JSON.stringify({ name, email, password });, I get an empty request. Why is that happening?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: There is no error, error happens then because the request is empty

Comment: I don't see `name` variable in login function.

Comment: const body = JSON.stringify({email, password });
It's like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set header to `application/json` since by default it is `application/json`. So, you should just send the raw data instead of stringify-ed data.

Here is a related thread in [GitHub](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1440#issuecomment-379355382).

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although, I still do not understand why it's acceptable to send raw data, but not stringify-ed data.